# Reading a Line from text file and return back

Tags: c#, text, file-io

I am developing a C# application in which I need to read a line from a text file and return back to first of line.

As file size may be too large I can't copy it into an array .

I tried this code

```
StreamReader str1 = new StreamReader(@"c:\file1.txt");
StreamReader str2 = new StreamReader(@"c:\file2.txt");

int a, b;
long pos1, pos2;

while (!str1.EndOfStream && !str2.EndOfStream)
{
    pos1 = str1.BaseStream.Position;
    pos2 = str2.BaseStream.Position;

    a = Int32.Parse(str1.ReadLine());
    b = Int32.Parse(str2.ReadLine());
    if (a <= b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File1 ---> " + a.ToString());
        str2.BaseStream.Seek(pos2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File2 ---> " + b.ToString());
        str1.BaseStream.Seek(pos1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
}
```

When I debuged the program I found out `str1.BaseStream.Position` and `str2.BaseStream.Position` are same in every loop , so nothing will change.

Is there any better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way Which I prefer to use.

Create a Function like this:

```
string ReadLine( Stream sr,bool goToNext)
        {            
            if (sr.Position >= sr.Length)
                return string.Empty;            
            char readKey;
            StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
            long position = sr.Position;
            do
            {
                readKey = (char)sr.ReadByte();
                strb.Append(readKey);
            }
            while (readKey != (char)ConsoleKey.Enter && sr.Position<sr.Length);
            if(!goToNext)
            sr.Position = position;
            return strb.ToString();        
        }
```

Then , Create a stream from file for It's argument

```
Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) for large file, it is *deferred execution* and does not load the whole file into memory, so you can manipulate lines in `IEnumerable` type:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("path");
```

If you are in old .NET version, below is how to build `ReadLines` by yourself:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> ReadLine(string path)
    {
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            while((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , Is there any way to do it with out reading whole file?

Comment: @Arashdn: did you try this way? this way is not reading the whole file

Comment: I am using old version of .net which does not contain File.ReadLines